# Why is the $F_{X}(x)={\mathcal {L}}^{-1}\left\{{\frac {1}{s}}E\left[e^{-sX}\right]\right\}(x)$?

Tags: probability-theory, laplace-transform

According to Wikipedia, the cumulative distribution function can be obtained from the Laplace transform as follows: $F_{X}(x)={\mathcal {L}}^{-1}\left\{{\frac {1}{s}}E\left[e^{-sX}\right]\right\}(x)$

Where does this result come from?

Comment: What do you know about Laplace transforms? How can we answer usefully if you do not say?

Comment: I was learning the topic directly from Wikipedia. Do you have a suggestion for a better introduction that I might use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Time-domain integration property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Properties_and_theorems):
$${\mathcal {L}}\left\{\int_0^x f(t) dt\right\}(s)=\frac{{\mathcal {L}}\left\{f(x)\right\}(s)}{s}.$$
Hence
$${\mathcal {L}}\left\{F_X(x)\right\}(s)={\mathcal {L}}\left\{\int_0^x f(t) dt\right\}(s)=\frac{{\mathcal {L}}\left\{f(x)\right\}(s)}{s}=\frac{1}{s}\int_0^{+\infty} f(x)e^{-sx} dx={\frac {1}{s}}E\left[e^{-sX}\right]$$
where $f$ is the probability density function of the random variable $X$.